# When I import firebase from "firebase", error can't resolve firebase occurs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am building a login and registration. I have a firebase.js file in src folder, and have done npm i firebase I then wrote import firebase from 'firebase';
and now i have an error that says
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/al/Desktop/amazon_clone_sep2021/amazon-clone/src'

Can anyone help me? I am following a tutorial and i am 3 hours in. This is my first big error i have encountered[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[

Comment: Have you run `npm install` or `yarn install`?

Comment: What SDK version are you importing? Also: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

You must do

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

for the import to work now.

I believe

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
```

was the old way to do it but will no longer works

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your import statement to

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

as advised in official firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)